# Which build system did eclipse use to build android apk?

Tags: android, eclipse, build, gradle, system

Now , google have a new build system to build apk -- gradle;I used it,but ,I think it is not  stable.The apk built by gradle is not same as the one built by eclipse.I want to know which build system did eclipse use? Is it Ant? If it is , how can I use command line to control it.
I just want to use command line instead of visual interface;How can I do that?

Comment: [This might help](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I used it,but ,I think it is not stable

You are welcome to your opinion. I have not run into problems with it to date, and many major organizations are using it for production apps. If you are running into specific problems, ask questions here or on [various Android developer support sites](http://www.andglobe.com).

> I want to know which build system did eclipse use?

Eclipse uses Eclipse-ADT.

> Is it Ant?

No. Ant is a separate build system, as is Maven.

> I just want to use command line instead of visual interface;How can I do that?

Use Gradle (Google-supported) or Maven (community-supported). Ant support, by pretty much all parties, is fading away.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excerpt from the official [Ant Reference:](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html#AntReference)

`ant clean`
Cleans the project. If you include the all target before clean (ant all clean), other projects are also cleaned. For instance if you clean a test project, the tested project is also cleaned.

`ant debug` 
Builds a debug package. Works on application, library, and test projects and compiles dependencies as needed.

`ant emma debug`
Builds a test project while building the tested project with instrumentation turned on. This is used to run tests with code coverage enabled.

`ant release`
Builds a release package.

`ant instrument`
Builds an instrumented debug package. This is generally called automatically when building a test project with code coverage enabled (with the emma target)

`ant <build_target> install`
Builds and installs a package. Using install by itself fails.

`ant installd`
Installs an already compiled debug package. This fails if the .apk is not already built.

`ant installr`
Installs an already compiled release package. This fails if the .apk is not already built.

`ant installt`
Installs an already compiled test package. Also installs the .apk of the tested application. This fails if the .apk is not already built.

`ant installi`
Installs an already compiled instrumented package. This is generally not used manually as it's called when installing a test package. This fails if the .apk is not already built.

`ant test`
Runs the tests (for test projects). The tested and test .apk files must be previously installed.

`ant debug installt test`
Builds a test project and the tested project, installs both .apk files, and runs the tests.

`ant emma debug install test`
Builds a test project and the tested project, installs both .apk files, and runs the tests with code coverage enabled.